# Problems installing older version of Bioconductor's mixOmics packages in R

Tags: r, package, bioconductor, renv

I've spent the day trying to load the appropriate package versions in R that I saved in a renv lockfile.

I used the package RVAideMemoire which is tied in with mixOmics in bioconductor, which can't be loaded automatically using `renv::restore()`.

I followed the steps outlined here to install the appropriate version of bioconductor (3.11) to get moxOmics version 6.12.1.

[R how to install a specified version of a bioconductor package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487171/r-how-to-install-a-specified-version-of-a-bioconductor-package)

Unfortunately I ended up with mixOmics version 6.14.1.
I attempted to load the earlier version using:

```
BiocManager::install("mixOmics", version = '6.12.1')
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
Error: version '6.12.1' must have two components, e.g., '3.7'
```

This seemed somewhat unclear, and I thought the additional ".1" at the end might be causing problems, but what I tried loading the version omitting the last ".1" as shown:

```
BiocManager::install("mixOmics", version = "6.12")
```

I got another error:

```
Error: unknown Bioconductor version '6.12'; see https://bioconductor.org/install
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here. The `renv::restore()` function won't complete the update as long as the mixOmics package install keeps failing, so I seem to be a bit stuck until I can get this straightened out.

**EDIT**
Just to provide some more info for the renv error, here's the message I get:

> Error: failed to retrieve package 'mixOmics'
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In system2("curl", args$data(), stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
> running command '"curl" --config "C:/Users/Corey/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuYYvKB/renv-tempdir-3d7050aa2ac3/renv-download-config-3d7076f57e1c"' had status 22
> 2: In downloader(url, destfile, type, request, headers) :
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
> 3: In system2("curl", args$data(), stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
> running command '"curl" --config "C:/Users/Corey/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuYYvKB/renv-tempdir-3d7050aa2ac3/renv-download-config-3d701ff05e24"' had status 22
> 4: In downloader(url, destfile, type, request, headers) :
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404`

After trying initial suggestion of using
`options(renv.settings.bioconductor.version = "3.11")   renv::install("bioc::mixOmics@6.12.1")`
I got the following errors:

> 'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details
> replacement repositories: CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com
> Querying repositories for available binary packages ... Done!
> Querying repositories for available source packages ... Done!
> Retrieving 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/bioc/src/contrib/Archive/mixOmics/mixOmics_6.12.1.tar.gz' ...
> Retrieving 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/annotation/src/contrib/Archive/mixOmics/mixOmics_6.12.1.tar.gz' ...
> Retrieving 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/experiment/src/contrib/Archive/mixOmics/mixOmics_6.12.1.tar.gz' ...
> Retrieving 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/workflows/src/contrib/Archive/mixOmics/mixOmics_6.12.1.tar.gz' ...
> Retrieving 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/books/src/contrib/Archive/mixOmics/mixOmics_6.12.1.tar.gz' ...
> Retrieving 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/mixOmics/mixOmics_6.12.1.tar.gz' ...
> Error: failed to retrieve package 'mixOmics'
> In addition: There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BiocManager::install()` doesn't provide an interface for installing specific versions of a package. The documentation for the version argument states:

> version: 'character(1)' *Bioconductor* version to install, e.g.,
> 'version = "3.8"'. The special symbol 'version = "devel"'
> installs the current 'development' version.

That is, it relates to the Bioconductor version, not the package version.

That said, you should be able to use `renv` to install a specific version of the package from Bioconductor. For example:

```
options(renv.settings.bioconductor.version = "3.11")
renv::install("bioc::mixOmics@6.12.1")
```

You could also use `renv::settings$bioconductor.version("3.11")` to store the required version of Bioconductor as a project setting, to be used by `renv` during `restore()`.

> I used the package RVAideMemoire which is tied in with mixOmics in bioconductor, which can't be loaded automatically using renv::restore().

I'd be curious to know why `renv::restore()` is failing for you.

EDIT: Based on your output, you're trying to use Bioconductor 3.12, but mixOmics 6.12.1 isn't available from that version of Bioconductor. You need to set the Bioconductor version used by `renv` as detailed in this answer. (You might also need to install the latest version of `renv` to gain support for this.)

Comment: I updated the initial error message as well as the error that resulted when trying the approach you provided

Comment: Updating renv before running the following code did the trick!
options(renv.settings.bioconductor.version = "3.11")
renv::install("bioc::mixOmics@6.12.1")
Was able to load the rest of the packages without incident after that.
Thanks!